# How to choose field for Related List - Single Control in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning, related-list

How do I specify fields for Related List - Single Control in Salesforce Lightning? What determines which fields are displayed?

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the columns on the related lists?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "fields" on Related List - Single?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

To Modify the columns on the related lists in lightning experience.

1. Setup
2. Object Manager
3. Select parent Object on which you have related list
4. PageLayout
5. Edit
6. Scroll down to the related lists section
7. Click wrench icon on the related list
8. Here you will be able to configure by moving up or down to adjust columns or Add or Remove.(Save your page layout once done).

Answer (score 2):

> You can customize the buttons, columns displayed, column order, and
>   record sort order of related lists on record detail pages in
>   Salesforce and the Salesforce Customer Portal. You can customize the
>   buttons, columns displayed, column order, and record sort order of
>   related lists on record detail pages in Salesforce and the Salesforce
>   Customer Portal.

1. Access the page layout editor.
2. To edit a related list, double-click it. If you’re using the
   enhanced page layout editor, you can also click the wrench icon
   (Wrench icon).
3. Select which fields to include in the related list, define the order
   in which the fields display, and select the record sort order. The default sort order is by record ID.You can include up to 10 fields per related list. If desired, select other page layouts to apply your related list customizations to.
4. Only layouts that include this related list appear in the list.
   Layouts that include related lists with the same customizations as the current layout had when you opened it is selected by default.
5. Click OK to store your customizations. Changes aren’t saved until
   you save the page layout.
6. Select Overwrite users’ customized related lists to apply the
   related lists in the page layout to all users, even if they have already customized their display.
7. Save the page layout.

> **Note:-** Currently the Lightning Experience UI only allows to display 4 fields on a related list. You would need to click "View All"
>   to see all fields. This is a regressed functionality, given the fact
>   that the same layout in classic version is capable of displaying 10
>   fields in the related section.

Whatever changes you will do following above process, It will be reflected in both classic and Lightning. Only Lightning has limitation it can display 4 fields at a time.

So, for your question, follow the above process, you will be able to customize the related list whichever you want. Related List-single is something you can add one related list at a time instead of adding all the related list at a time.

Reference:-

1. [Customize Related Lists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_related_lists.htm&type=5)
2. [Idea to allow More than 4 fields on Related List in Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEFbQAM)